# BIBO stability of a time-varying linear system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

> Prove that the following time-varying system is BIBO stable.
> $$ \begin{aligned} & \begin{bmatrix} \dot{x_1} \\ \dot{x_2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -t & 0 \\ 2t-1 & -2t \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} e^{-t} \\ e^{-2t} \end{bmatrix}u(t)\\ &\\ & \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\ \sin(t) & -\cos(t) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \end{aligned} $$

---

I tried to find the eigenvalues $\lambda_i(t)$ of $A(t)$ and they are indeed negative (i.e., $ \lambda_1(t) = -t $, $ \lambda_2(t) = -2t $ ) for $t\gt0$ but my textbook mentions that the eigenvalue method is only applicable to time-invariant systems.

If I consider $A$ static for any given time and show that its eigenvalues are negative for any $t\in T$, is that an acceptable proof?

Comment: No, it is not correct in general. There are many counterexamples to that.

Comment: Also, could you please check whether the matrix $A(t)$ is correct?

Comment: You can't even conclude that some LTV system is unstable if it has a strictly positive eigenvalue for all $t$.

Comment: What are the tools supposed for this example? It should be rather straightforward with a Lyapunov function.

Comment: @KBS In the original source, in the bottom-left part of the A(t) matrix it said "2t-t" which I assumed was wrong and translated it as "2t-1" but I cannot confirm that. The rest is correct.

Comment: @Arastas I tried to prove it with the Lyapunov function but couldn't prove negative semi-definite derivative (maybe a problem with my math). I was also not sure if proof of Lyapunov stability proves BIBO stability.

Comment: @FrankFourlas what is the source?

Comment: @KBS Past exam on my uni (It's in Greek so I can't share the original). Funny thing is I passed the class on Wednesday and don't need help anymore but it still bothers me.

Comment: @FrankFourlas Language is not an issue for this kind of things.

Comment: @FrankFourlas As to me, it is enough to show that the Lyapunov function is OK for $t>T$ for some $T$ and not for all $t$.

Comment: @Arastas How can you exclude the possibility of finite escape time for $t \leq T$ in this case?

Comment: @SampleTime There is no finite escape-time for such a system.

Comment: @SampleTime It is a linear TV system with bounded gains. I am not aware of the finite-time escape phenomena for this case.

Comment: @Arastas I think you are right (although I am not sure what you mean with bounded gains). I remembered that LTV systems can have finite escape time when $A(t)$ is unbounded (like in the question) but this is not sufficient. For example $A(t)=1/(t - 1)$ is unbounded and the LTV system $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ has finite escape time but that is only because $A(t)$ itself escapes in finite time.

Comment: @SampleTime The system here is Lipschitz for each $t\ge0$, so it cannot have a finite-escape time. $A(t)$ is locally bounded and this is enough.

Comment: @SampleTime with "bounded gains" I mean that all elements of $A$ are bounded on any finite interval.